# Why should we expect duality to give useful concepts in category theory?

Tags: category-theory, intuition

Why should we expect the abstract notion of flipping arrows in a category to generate useful concepts from other useful ones? What exactly does flipping the direction of arrows mean and why is it universally useful? It certainly does not seem to be anything meaningful in any concrete category itself(or does it)?

Edit:I can see that duals are useful anyway since they generate free proofs but this would not answer my question.

The main question here is I suppose: Why would one expect dual concepts to be non vacuous before actually taking duals and checking?

Comment: Here's a silly philosophical answer: what is actually useful is *simple* concepts, and the dual of a simple concept is another simple concept.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I did consider that but I am not sure if there are lots of simple concepts that do not turn out to be useful. Is it the case that almost anything one can define in category theory that is "simple" turns out to be useful? If so, that would probably settle my question.

Answer (score 5):

> [Flipping arrows] certainly does not seem to be anything meaningful in any concrete category itself (or does it)?

There *are* cases where the opposite of a familiar category constructed by arrow-flipping is, or is equivalent to, another category of real interest (rather than an artificial construct): the opposite of the category $\mathbf{Set}$ is equivalent to the category of complete atomic boolean algebras (a surprise when you first hear it, perhaps).

But ok, suppose for the sake of argument that there are relatively few such examples: suppose that flipping arrows only rarely takes from an intrinsically interesting category to some other category we might want to investigate for 'concrete', non-category-theoretic, reasons. This perhaps is perhaps the thought underlying the question.

No matter! *Arrow-flipping would still be a useful technique, giving us proofs by duality*. For a baby example, if we show that in every category terminal objects are unique up to unique isomorphism, then -- remembering that categories come in pairs related by arrow-flipping -- it will follow by duality, i.e. by arrow-flipping, that every initial object is unique up to unique isomorphism. And so it goes.

The importance of arrow-flipping, i.e. of duality considerations like this, in producing buy-one-get-one-free proofs does *not* depend on the flipped version of particular interesting categories being themselves *interesting*. It only depends on categories *having* duals, interesting or otherwise.

And it can hardly be denied that the resulting duals of useful theorems are very often useful too! To take obvious examples, some familiar constructions are, in category theory terms, *products*, and other constructions are *coproducts*. It isn't that the one kind, products, is inhabited and its dual, coproducts, is empty! Likewise some constructions which are familiar pre-categorially turn out to be *equalizers*, other familiar constructions turn out to be *coequalizers*. Dualizing theorems about products and equalizers gives us theorems about coproducts and coequalizers -- and there are indeed familiar examples of such things! So yes, both the  theorems about products and equalizers and their duals  have interesting applications.

Comment: I was trying to ask why it is that the resulting duals of useful theorems are very often useful too. I am sorry if it wasn't clear and look forward to any ideas you might have.

Comment: I have added a paragraph.

Comment: I am sorry to sound like a broken clock but I think you are just giving more examples? I was trying to find something like a reason for why one should expect the dual concepts to be non empty before actually taking duals and looking. There might be none of course.